# Show a div with hidden parent

Tags: jquery, html

How to show a div whose parent is hidden?

```
<div class='hidden' style="display:none">
    <div class='visible' style="display:block">
        Div Content

    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mnajstt/

Comment: move the div outside of the parent.

Comment: `visibility:hidden` on the parent, `visibility:visible` on the child

Comment: By definition an included div will always be hidden if the parent is.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ: uh, what? exactly how would leaving a safety deposit box open inside a bank vault make the box's contents visible? You can't "visible" something inside a hidden container. -1 if I could.

Comment: @MarcB http://jsfiddle.net/5mnajstt/1/ yes you can. You can't do this with display however, as display removes the parent from the flow.

Comment: I need to know if I can do it with jquery using display:none, display :block

Comment: @nath: yeah, my bad... I'll just go crawl over into this corner here and hide my head in the sand. visibility != display. sorry.

Comment: visibility:hidden occupies the div space, while display:none doesn't

Comment: Maybe if you explained what it is you are trying to accomplish in more detail we might be able to offer an alternative approach.

Comment: @MarcB I just learned something new too (:

Comment: @MarcB don't feel bad, I assumed same since rarely use `visible` and logic of it doesn't make sense

Comment: Actually, in the above code we can get the hidden parent, but if the div is a nested child to some extent, it would be difficult to get the exactly hidden parent. So I need a way to directly show the child from its own element.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? It makes no sense to display something inside a hidden div, because the hidden div takes no space. Where would the displayed DIV go? Maybe what you really want to do is hide all the other children of the outer DIV except the child you want to show.

Comment: It is possible using CSS. If you are ok with using CSS I can post the code.

Comment: Basically its not about the direct child to a div, just assume that we don't know the parent, infact the hidden parent of the desired div, how could this be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class='hidden'>
<div class='visible'>
    Div Content     
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden>div
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.hidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5mnajstt/3/)**

**OR**

You can make a `clone` of `hidden div` and then `append` it to another div. Like this:

```
<div class='hidden' style="display:none">
<div class='visible'>
    Div Content
</div>
</div>
<div id="dv"> </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
var element = jQuery('.visible').clone();
element.appendTo('#dv');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5mnajstt/5/)**

Comment: I don't want to use visibility:hidden and visibility:visible.

Comment: then you can use the second method. It doesn't involves `visibiity`